# Ansible Tower: Writing job stdout to files

Tags: ansible-awx, ansible-tower

Is there any way in Ansible Tower to create log files for the each job stdout? I am aware that the below API will show me the output.

```
https://<tower_ip>/api/v2/jobs/<job id>/stdout/
```

But we also want these output into separate files for each job. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

According the [Tower API Reference Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html) **Jobs** it is possible to get via REST API call a formatted downloadable plain text, in example

```
curl --silent -u ${TOWER_USER}:${TOWER_PASSWORD} --location https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/jobs/${JobID}/stdout?format=txt_download --output job_${JobID}.log
```

and write it into a file like `job_${JobID}.log`.

**Thanks to**

- [`man curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)